# Using column short-names defined previously in the same SQL statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm making some statistics from a table having values for expected and actual results.

this statement works perfectly:

```
select model_ref AS [Model],
     count(id) AS Tested,
     count(case when expected_result = predicted_result then predicted_result end) AS OK,
     count(case when NOT(expected_result = predicted_result) then expected_result end) AS Wrong,
     ( (count(case when expected_result = predicted_result then predicted_result end)*1.0) / count(id) * 100  ) AS [Accuracy (%)]
from Results
```

but this not:

```
select model_ref AS [Model],
     count(id) AS Tested,
     count(case when expected_result = predicted_result then predicted_result end) AS OK,
     count(case when NOT(expected_result = predicted_result) then expected_result end) AS Wrong,
     ( OK *1.0) / Tested * 100  ) AS [Accuracy (%)]
from Results
```

The difference is only, I wanted to shorten the expression by using column names defined previously - *Tested* and *OK*

Is it possible?

P.S.:
If it is of any importance, the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Results(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
expected_result TEXT,
image_id TEXT,
model_ref TEXT,
predicted_result TEXT,
test_date TEXT)
```

Comment: AS doesn't shorten the column name , it just provides an alternative name in the result set. You can't reuse it in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most databases an alias can't be used on the same "level" (or scope) of the query as it has been defined (as it might not be possible to resolve the alias at the time the query is parsed). What you could do is to wrap the query in an outer query which would have access to the alias like this:

```
select 
    Model,
    Tested,
    OK,
    Wrong,
    (( OK *1.0) / Tested * 100  ) AS [Accuracy (%)] 
from (
    select model_ref AS [Model],
       count(id) AS Tested,
       count(case when expected_result = predicted_result then predicted_result end) AS OK,
       count(case when NOT(expected_result = predicted_result) then expected_result end) AS Wrong
    from Results
    group by model_ref
) a
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! After I've posted my question I've found out that my query outputs only one line, regardless how many model_ref I have. But yours works perfectly! Also the usage of aliases is now clear to me.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz The reason it only output on e row was probably due to the missing `group by` clause in your original query. Using aggregate functions without grouping isn't allowed in most databases (MySQL being a notable exception, and apparently SQLite too).