# SQLite. How to calculate sum of aggregated columns

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions

For example, I have query like that:

```
select 
    pc.[Sum] as PlanSum,
    case when Sum(TransferOut.[Sum]) is null then 0 else Sum(TransferOut.[Sum]) end as TOut,
    case when Sum(TransferIn.[Sum]) is null then 0 else Sum(TransferIn.[Sum]) end as TIn        

from PlannedCost pc
left join Transfer TransferOut on pc.id = TransferOut.PlanCostFromId
left join Transfer TransferIn on pc.id = TransferOut.PlanCostToId
```

and if I change my query in order to calculate columns like that:

```
    pc.[Sum] as PlanSum,
    case when Sum(TransferOut.[Sum]) is null then 0 else Sum(TransferOut.[Sum]) end as TOut,
    case when Sum(TransferIn.[Sum]) is null then 0 else Sum(TransferIn.[Sum]) end as TIn,
    (pc.[Sum] - TOut + TIn) as CountedPlanSum,
```

I'm getting an error :

> no such column: TOut

how can I calculate my columns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using column short-names defined previously in the same SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764070/using-column-short-names-defined-previously-in-the-same-sql-statement)

Comment: I think it's not exactly what I need...

Comment: That is exactly what you need.