# No such column exists for subquery result sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm converting mysql query to sqlite query and I have problem in using **alias name** further in sqlite query as explained below,

I have two tables as below,

```
table1 -> (id, firstname, lastname)
table2 -> (id, cityname)
```

I want to perform subquery eg

```
select 
       firstname, lastname,

       (select 
              cityname
        from
               table2
        where 
               id=1
       ) as city                                            <<<<<===== city alias works fine
from
    table1
```

Result would be,

```
 firstname    lastname    city
```

**Problem is when I want to utilize `city alias` further in query.**

eg. to city alias result, I want to append "pink city"

```
select 
           firstname, lastname,
    
           (select 
                  cityname
            from
                   table2
            where 
                   id=1
           ) as city                                           <<<<<===== city alias works fine


           ( select city || "pink city" ) as citywithcredit    <<==== here it says city column doesn't exist (In Mysql same query works without problem)
    from
        table1
```

Comment: You can't use an alias in other fields of the same select, no. They're not in scope in those expressions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using column short-names defined previously in the same SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764070/using-column-short-names-defined-previously-in-the-same-sql-statement)

Comment: @Shawn interesting it works very well with mysql but not with sqlite. Yes, provided link answer could be my ultimate solution but that way my query will become very complex and I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've hard coded `id=1` then I'm assuming the ID of first table does not relate to the second table.

You could use multiple statements in the FROM clause.

```
select 
  firstname, 
  lastname, 
  city.cityname || "pink city" as citywithcredit
from
  table1,
  (select cityname
   from table2
   where id=1
  ) as city
```

If the ID's of the tables do relate then you can join them with a where clause like below.

```
select 
  firstname, 
  lastname, 
  city.cityname || "pink city" as citywithcredit
from
  table1,
  (select id, cityname
   from table2
  ) as city
where table1.id = city.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original query assumes that data can be processed during the selection of columns (i.e., after the joins have been performed).
This does not appear to be possible in SQLite.  You'll need to perform the aliasing/manipulation before the join, and this can be done in one of two ways:

1. You can use a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
sqlite> create table table1 (id int, firstname varchar, lastname varchar);
sqlite> insert into table1 values (1,'john','doe');
sqlite> create table table2 (id int, cityname varchar);
sqlite> insert into table2 values (1,'london');
sqlite> with c as (select cityname as city
   ...>              from table2
   ...>             where id=1
   ...>           )
   ...> select firstname, lastname, c.city, c.city || 'pink city' as citywithcredit
   ...>     from c, table1;  -- add any additional WHERE clause here as needed
+-----------+----------+--------+-----------------+
| firstname | lastname |  city  | citywithcredit  |
+-----------+----------+--------+-----------------+
| john      | doe      | london | londonpink city |
+-----------+----------+--------+-----------------+
```

2. You can use a sub-query in the `FROM` clause:

```
sqlite> SELECT 
   ...>   firstname, 
   ...>   lastname, 
   ...>   c.city,
   ...>   c.city || "pink city" as citywithcredit
   ...> FROM
   ...>   table1,
   ...>   (SELECT cityname as city
   ...>      FROM table2
   ...>     WHERE id=1
   ...>   ) as c;
+-----------+----------+--------+-----------------+
| firstname | lastname |  city  | citywithcredit  |
+-----------+----------+--------+-----------------+
| john      | doe      | london | londonpink city |
+-----------+----------+--------+-----------------+
```